# Why are .show() and .hide() toggling even though I'm not using toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to hide the `div#errorLog` if there are no errors and show it if there are. The jQuery detects errors fine and execution is going through the if statement without a problem. However, when executing the code, the `hide()` will show the `div` if it is already hidden and the `show()` will hide the `div` if it's already showing.

I'm using IE 11. It works without a problem in Firefox. Why is are `show()` and `hide()` acting as toggles?

**HTML Code (Excluding master page):**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Title" runat="server">
    <title>Login</title>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Login" ContentPlaceHolderID="Log_orReg" runat="server">
    <h1 class="chosen"><a href="Login.aspx">Login</a></h1>
    <h1 class="inline">|</h1>
    <h1 class="notChosen"><a href="Register.aspx">Register</a></h1>
    <br />

    <form id="LoginForm" style="margin: 5px; " runat="server">
        <div class="fill">Username:</div><asp:TextBox id="Username" CssClass="textboxes" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldUsername" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must enter a username." ControlToValidate="Username"  Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <div class="fill">Password:</div><asp:TextBox id="Password" CssClass="textboxes" TextMode="Password" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldPassword" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must enter a password." ControlToValidate="Password" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:button ID="LogReg_btn" CssClass="LogReg_btn" onclick="cmd_submit" runat="server" Text="Login"></asp:button>
        <div id="errorLog" class="Error_Log" runat="server">
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="false" DisplayMode="BulletList" ShowSummary="true" ShowValidationErrors="true" />
        </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Error_Log').hide();
    var bottom = $(".LogReg_forms").position().top + $('.LogReg_forms').outerHeight(true);
    var position = parseInt(bottom + 10) + "px";

    $(".Error_Log").css('top', position);

    $(".LogReg_btn").click(function () {
        var isPageValid = Page_ClientValidate('');

        if (isPageValid == true) {
            $(".Error_Log").hide("fade");
        }
        else {
            $(".Error_Log").show("fade");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems like it is because you are posting back to the server and the page submits and resets the button to the state it was originally in. Or is the animation just working and the page is not posting back?

Comment: It doesn't answer your "why" question, but one alternative you have is to use `toggle` and pass it a bool argument, so you can collapse your click function down to one line: `$(".Error_Log").toggle(!Page_ClientValidate(''))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. This problem is with jquery version 1.6. If you're experiencing this problem, make sure your updated to the latest jquery version.